# Which is idiomatic, 'a small quantity' or 'a little quantity'?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

Which of these is idiomatic, 'a small quantity' or 'a little quantity?

For instance:

> This product has a little / small quantity of that ingredient.

Answer (score 6):

In general, words like "amount," "quantity," "number," etc all use "small" rather than "little."  So "a small quantity of cases," "a small amount of chips," and so on.

However, your sentence has another issue: ingredients don't have quantity (small or otherwise), you can only have some quantity of an ingredient. So you would properly say "This product contains a small quantity of this ingredient." Alternatively, you can say "there is a small quantity of this ingredient in this product."

Comment: "A little quantity of..." is found in Google searches, very often in material from Nigeria. I agree that it is not standard or formal English.

Comment: I edited my instance.

Comment: @VirtuousLegend editing your post *after* someone has pointed out its errors, means a chunk of this answer is invalid. You should rollback the edit.

Comment: Actually I think numbers tend to be more often low or high than small or big.

Comment: @Stef - I would say that both low/high and small/large (or 'big', less formal) are fine.

Comment: @Stef "a small number of people were at the party,"  not "a low number of people" (and definitely not "a little number of people")

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, I shouldn't (The answer can be edited as well). In such cases of which the answer is focusing on the thing which is not the main question and distracts the main question for future questioners, like in this case. I am ok with your disagreement. However, it was important for me to show the other side of the coin. Cheers.

Comment: @VirtuousLegend no, you are not supposed to edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Answerers are not expected to keep up with your question and edit their answers accordingly. Plus, it isn't a negative to leave that mistake in your question, and this answer did answer the question you asked, along with giving other info that could help other learners. You, or someone else if you refuse, should rollback your question edit.

Comment: @Esther It isn't about negativeness, but rather about focusing. If the main question is a mistake I would leave it as it is, as my early background shows, then indeed no reason to edit the question according to the answer. However, in this case, it was really a thing that I would change by myself if I read it again after sleeping enough time... Focusing on that, really lost the question I wanted to ask here.

Answer (score 3):

That 'instance' is not grammatical with 'small' or 'little'. You can say 'This ingredient **is present in** a small [or little] quantity in this product'. Since is 'present in' is formal English, I would prefer using the formal 'small' and not 'little', although a Google search will find examples of that usage.

> Carbon dioxide (CO2) is present in a small quantity in the air we
> breathe (0.04%). It is colourless, tasteless, non-flammable, and has a
> very faint sour smell.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly "a smidgen", given that the first example in a Google search for a usage of the word is pretty much the example in your question ("a small amount of something" -
"add a smidgen of cayenne" per Oxford dictionaries. [Similar definition and example in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smidgen)).

Comment: Informal, and maybe OK in an informally written recipe, or in casual conversation, but not generally, especially not in a formal or academic context.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I doubt that somebody who is writing in an academic context would have asked for an "idiomatical," (sic) expression (idiomatic after all means "correct without being too formal").

Comment: But 'this product has... of that ingredient', as in the question, is decidedly formal. Something can be idiomatic and completely informal (not just 'without being too formal'), e.g. I don't think you would write 'We must not shit in our own nest' in a business plan or political manifesto.

Comment: Many 2nd-language learners, and also native speakers use 'idiomatic' to mean 'correct' or 'natural'. Cambridge Dictionary, for example, gives these two definitions: (1) containing or consisting of an idiom (example given: 'bite the bullet') (2) containing expressions that are natural and correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).